# Same fingering position for fingering notation and \finger command in LilyPond?

Tags: fingering, lilypond, engraving

I have found that fingering notation and `\finger` command in LilyPond place fingering differently. How to make `finger` command behave the same way as `^n`, `_n`, `-n` notations? Here is a MWE:

```
\version "2.22"
\include "italiano.ly"

\relative do'' {
    \key sol \minor
    <<
        {
            do2 <sib re>4 <do mib>4
        } \\
        {
            mib,4 (
                \once\set fingeringOrientations = #'(down)
                <sol \finger \markup \tied-lyric #"2~1">
            ) s s
        }
    >>
}
```

The result is not satisfactory:

[image]

I would rather prefer the placement of the fingering notation (to the right of the stem, just under the staff):

```
\version "2.22"
\include "italiano.ly"

\relative do'' {
    \key sol \minor
    <<
        {
            do2 <sib re>4 <do mib>4
        } \\
        {
            mib,4 (
                \once\set fingeringOrientations = #'(down)
                <sol_2>
            ) s s
        }
    >>
}
```

The result:

[image]

Is there a way to do it with `\finger`?

Comment: As a performer,  I strongly recommend **against** pushing the number up there.  Fingering numbers are much easier to  handle when they are directly over (or under) the stem of the note.

Comment: I engrave this for myself, not for publishing. For me, when I perform, I don't care about fingering. Fingering is just for practice, and thus I don't want it to occupy extra space. Besides, it's not that I am doing something extravagant, I am just mimicking the default behavior of LilyPond's fingering notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
\version "2.22"
\include "italiano.ly"

\relative do'' {
    \key sol \minor
    <<
        {
            do2 <sib re>4 <do mib>4
        } \\
        {
            mib,4 (
                \once \set fingeringOrientations = #'(down)
                \once \override Fingering.self-alignment-X = #LEFT
                <sol \finger \markup \tied-lyric #"2~1">
            ) s s
        }
    >>
}
```

[image]